# Adding pubsubhubbub link tag to Atom feed

Tags: publish-subscribe, feed, atom-feed, websub

According to [Google](https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/) the link tag containing the URL to the pubsubhubbub hub (This is a really terrible name) needs to go under the Atom entry element like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:lang="en-GB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <!-- ... -->
  <entry>
    <link rel="hub" href="https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </entry>
</feed>
```

However, all the implementations and blog posts I have seen add it to the feed element instead like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:lang="en-GB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <!-- ... -->
  <link rel="hub" href="https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/" />
  <entry>
    <!-- ... -->
  </entry>
</feed>
```

What is the correct location for it?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux it is directly on the front page: `Add an //atom:link tag under //atom:entry for Atom feeds or under //rss:rss/channel for RSS feeds. The //atom:link tag should have rel attribute set to hub and href attribute set to https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/`

Comment: @JulienGenestoux Which hub is recommended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be at the feed level: http://pubsubhubbub.github.io/PubSubHubbub/pubsubhubbub-core-0.3.html#discovery (that is btw. the same spec, Google is referencing).

Comment: Thank you! I have now included this feature in [ASP.NET MVC Boilerplate](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6cf50a48-fc1e-4eaf-9e82-0b2a6705ca7d)